# Protobuf serialization length differs when using different values for field

Tags: c++, serialization, go, protocol-buffers

My Protobuf message consists of 3 doubles

```
syntax = "proto3";

message TestMessage{
  double input = 1;
  double output = 2;
  double info = 3;
}
```

When I set these values to

```
test.set_input(2.3456);
test.set_output(5.4321);
test.set_info(5.0);
```

the serialized message looks like

```
00000000  09 16 fb cb ee c9 c3 02  40 11 0a 68 22 6c 78 ba  |........@..h"lx.|
00000010  15 40 19                                          |.@.|
00000013
```

when using `test.serializeToArray` and could not be deserialized successfully by a go program using the same protobuf message. When trying to read it from a c++ program I got a 0 as info, so the message seems to be corrupted.

When using `test.serializeToOstream` I got this message, which could be deserialized successfully by both go and c++ programs.

```
00000000  09 16 fb cb ee c9 c3 02  40 11 0a 68 22 6c 78 ba  |........@..h"lx.|
00000010  15 40 19 00 00 00 00 00  00 14 40               |.@........@|
0000001b
```

When setting the values to

```
test.set_input(2.3456);
test.set_output(5.4321);
test.set_info(5.5678);
```

the serialized messages, both produced by `test.serializeToArray` and `test.serializeToOstream` look like

```
00000000  09 16 fb cb ee c9 c3 02  40 11 0a 68 22 6c 78 ba  |........@..h"lx.|
00000010  15 40 19 da ac fa 5c 6d  45 16 40                 |.@....\mE.@|
0000001b
```

and could be successfully read by my go and cpp program.

What am I missing here? Why is `serializeToArray` not working in the first case?

EDIT:
As it turns out, serializeToString works fine, too.

Here the code I used for the comparison:

```
file_a.open(FILEPATH_A);
file_b.open(FILEPATH_B);

test.set_input(2.3456);
test.set_output(5.4321);
test.set_info(5.0);

//serializeToArray
int size = test.ByteSize();
char *buffer = (char*) malloc(size);
test.SerializeToArray(buffer, size);
file_a << buffer;

//serializeToString
std::string buf;
test.SerializeToString(&buf);
file_b << buf;

file_a.close();
file_b.close();
```

Why does serializeToArray not work as expected?

EDIT2:

When using `file_b << buf.data()` instead of `file_b << buf.data()`, the data gets corrupted as well, but why?

Comment: You said in Go you get the same length, but what are you using when you get different lengths?

Comment: Yeah, the first version is just wrong IMO. It should be 27 bytes. You can put the hex in here https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode to verify and see the same numbers come out for the 27 byte version

Comment: When I do the same operations in go like I do in cpp, both serialized messages got the same length, in contrast to the cpp serialization which length differ

Comment: What does `size` come out as, BTW?

Comment: The `size` is 27, which should be correct if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error you're making is treating binary as character data and using character data APIs. Many of those APIs **stop** at the first nil byte (0), but that is a totally valid value in protobuf binary.

You need to make sure you don't use any such APIs basically - stick purely to binary safe APIs.

Since you indicate that `size` is 27, this all fits.

Basically, the binary representation of 5.0 includes 0 bytes, but you could easily have seen the same problem for other values in time.

Comment: So the issue is the `file_b << buffer` because I pass a char array and the ostream ends the writing after the first nil byte, since it's expecting a null terminated string?

Comment: @jonadev95 yes, exactly that